# Async fetch of data not rerendering ReactJS datatable(or just not displaying new data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, rerender

The problem here is that, if my new data is fetched from my backend(RestAPI), the datatable does not display the new data even though I called this.setState and if I log the new state, the fetched data gets logged to the console, but is not displayed in my datatable.
When I hardcode the data in the constructors this.state = xxx, the data gets displayed just fine. So I think this has to be related to some rerendering problem? I debugged for hours, but I just couldn't find the problem. It would be really great if somebody could help me out here :)

I read very much articles and posts about not rerendering and the lifecycle of react components. As further info, when I log the state in the render method before the return values, it is at first null (as I initialised the state), and after the second rendering the data is in this.state.rowData as desired. But I simply cant find out why it doesnt get displayed in the datatable.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            columnDefs: [{
                headerName: "Dump Name", field: "dumpName", sortable: true, filter: true
            }, {
                headerName: "Type", field: "type", sortable: true, filter: true
            }, {
                headerName: "Size", field: "length", sortable: true, filter: true
            }, {
                headerName: "Different CAN-IDs", field: "canIdCount", sortable: true, filter: true
            }, {
                headerName: "Created At", field: "createdAt", sortable: true, filter: true
            }],
            rowData: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        let collectionData = [];
        await getSniffs().then(function (sniffdata) {
            sniffdata.map(async function (row) {
                collectionData.push({
                    dumpName: row,
                    length: await getMessageCount(row).then(function (res) {
                        return res[0].all;
                    }),
                    canIdCount: await getIdCountDistinct(row).then(function (res) {
                        return res[0].count;
                    }),
                    createdAt: await getFirstTimestamp(row).then(function (res) {
                        return res[0].firstTimestamp;
                    }),
                    type: "CAN Message"
                });
            });
        }).then(() => this.setState({
            rowData: collectionData
        }));
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <div
                className="ag-theme-material"
                style={{
                    height: '500px',
                    width: '1000px' }}
            >
                <AgGridReact
                    // onRowClicked={this.onRowClicked.bind(this)}
                    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                    rowData={this.state.rowData}>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
            // : <Loading/>;
    )}
}

export default withRouter(SniffOverviewDatatable);
```

The datatable just shows: No Row to show.
At first I think thats the correct result, but it should get updated and show my retrieved data.
The logs display exactly the desired data and array-structure.

Thanks for your time and I really hope to get some hints :)

**EDIT:**
Hey hey I just rewrote the componentDidMount function, but it didnt change a thing, im afraid. Data gets logged, but table doesnt get updated :/

Here is the new code of the function (used async/await):

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
            let rowData = [];
            try {
                const sniffs = await getSniffs();
                sniffs.map(async function (row) {
                    const msgCount = await getMessageCount(row);
                    const idCount = await getIdCountDistinct(row);
                    const firstTimestamp = await getFirstTimestamp(row);

                    rowData.push({
                        dumpName: row,
                        length: msgCount[0].all,
                        canIdCount: idCount[0].count,
                        createdAt: firstTimestamp[0].firstTimestamp,
                        type: "CAN Message"
                    });
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            this.setState({
                rowData
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I just wanted to provide my own answer if anybo0dy looks at this question:

```
    componentDidMount = async () => {
    let fetched = await getSniffs();

    let rowData = [];

    for (const row of fetched.data) {
        const msgCount = await getMessageCount(row);
        const idCount = await getIdCountDistinct(row);
        const firstTimestamp = await getFirstTimestamp(row);

        rowData.push({
            dumpName: row,
            length: msgCount.data[0].all,
            canIdCount: idCount.data[0].count,
            createdAt: new Date(firstTimestamp.data[0].firstTimestamp),
            type: "CAN Message"
        });
    }

    this.setState({
        rowData
    });
};
```

This works just fine now :) I also migrated this method one Component above, so the datatable just gets its data via the props and not via state.
Thanks and closed!

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried using setState with a callback function and some kind of immutability library such as immutability-helper? This would lead to code like this:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
...

this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {rowData: {$set: collectionData}});
...
```

Comment: Hey :) thanks for the advice. I tested this and used this code snippet: 
`this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {rowData: {$set: rowData}}));`
Im afraid I got the same result as before:
https://ibb.co/S5Rj8Pq  -> Console.log of this.state.rowData in the render function.